# OpenCV C++ Remove Bright Spots and Oversaturation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a video feed in which I process each camera frame to detect certain objects. For the sake of robustness, I want to be able to identify and tone down parts of the frame where light (background and/or light emitted in the scene) causes oversaturation, resulting in white pixels. What is the best way of doing this?

[image: image with bright spots and light reflection]

Here is a binary threshold of a grayscale frame where lower bound = 221 and upper bound = 254 (thus the white pixels are areas of bright light and strong light reflections). There are 4 objects on the screen that are glowing, but also noise from background light reflected off the surface that the objects are situated. I want to filter out the reflected light, but keep the light from the glowing objects.

Comment: If the areas of the image are truly oversaturated, there is no way to "tone them down" in software. This has to be done by adjusting your exposure settings.

Comment: Can post examples in order to get a better idea of your problem?